# overlapping of geometries in Scenekit

Tags: blender, scenekit

I'm have put a plane onto the same height as the edges of the cube are. Everything you see was created in Blender and you can download Blender file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36945). The plane is a little bigger than the hole so that they overlap.[image]

The whole rendering is a little funny. I get this frame around the hole due to plane and cube edge having the same hight. I only want the plane to be visible. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I can always change height for a tinywiny bit but I would prefer a different approach due to shadows and reflections and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused because you are referring to a hole while it seems that your cube does not have any hole and your are adding a plane on top of it.

What you are seeing is called depth fighting and it's because both objects have the same z-value, yes.

`SCNMaterial` exposes properties like `writesToDepthBuffer` and `readsFromDepthBuffer` that can help with that. Also check `SCNNode`'s `renderingOrder` property.

Comment: The cube is hollow, you can check the .blend file for more information. Setting rendering order to 2 and 1 for plane and cube respectively didn't fix the problem. Setting cube's and plane's writesToDepthBuffer and readsFromDepthBuffer respectively did the job! Thank you!